# Does core data changedValues ignore binary data and transformed attributes?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I'm evaluating a core data entity via `changedValues` before saving the context so I can make some additional changes to the managed object.  In my case, I have some non-trivial calculations that are only relevant if the object truly changed.

I changed one of my attributes to binary data and added a transformer to store dictionary data.  The `changedValues` method always returns a nil dictionary or a dictionary without this attribute.

**ChangedValues from the documentation:**

> Return Value
>   A dictionary containing as keys the names of persistent properties that have changed since the receiver was last fetched or saved, and as values the new values of the properties.
>
> Discussion
>   This method only reports changes to properties that are defined as persistent properties of the receiver, not changes to transient properties or custom instance variables. This method does not unnecessarily fire relationship faults.

Does `changedValues` not return values for transformed attributes?  I have seen changedValues return the binary data attribute name in the dictionary when I stored things like images.

I've found no information in the documentation about valid entity attributes returned in the dictionary.

What's the best practice for determining if a managed object has been modified?

Thanks!

**Update:**
Here's the transformer I use to store a dictionary as binary object:

```
@implementation DictionaryToData
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSDictionary class];
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
}

@end
```

Comment: I would expect it to include every attribute regardless of type. Can you add some information about what data you're transforming and how you're doing this?

Comment: @Tom, I added code for my transformer.  Nothing fancy, just NSDictionary to/from binary data.  Interesting, I check the managed object's isUpdated property and it is set.

Comment: @Tom, I checked the managed object's isUpdated property and it is set.  Another odd observation is that changing the attribute via this transformer doesn't get picked up for use by my undoManager either.

Comment: Okay, as a test I removed the transformer and used NSKeyedArchiver, NSKeyedUnarchiver myself to convert the data to/from core data.  Now core data knows of the change and my undo manager again works.  This makes no sense and I can find no documentation of this behavior.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: The only reason I know why that transformer might fail would be if the dictionary contained non-archivable objects (i.e. something that didn't conform to `NSCoding`). Assuming you're using the same data both times though, that would also fail manual archiving.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary does cannot contain a binary. You have to fetch the binary separately (not in a dictionary) and transform it manually.

Comment: `NSDictionary` can contain any object including, for example `NSData`.

Comment: Hmm, I just read this yesterday. Something related to dictionaries can not contain NSData. I will investigate as I must have confused the instruction.

Comment: @DSMagic, I'm not having trouble transforming NSDictionary to/from binary data.  My issue is that core data doesn't list it as a modified attribute using changedValues to get a dictionary of changed values when the attribute is changed via a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing your accessor, you need to call `willAccessValueForKey:` and `didAccessValueForKey:` around your primitive access.

Likewise, when implementing your setter, you need to call `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` around your primitive setter.

Comment: This is true but is completely irrelevant to the question of value transformers.

Comment: I added that because a `NSDictionary` is `NSCoder` compliant, which means that you do not need a custom transformer at all... and the code the OP provided is a valid transformer implementation.  So, it must be something else... If it's a valid dictionary, one way to not get `changedValues` is to have a custom setter implementation, and forget to call the KVC willChange/didChange methods.  Probably should have been a comment rather than an answer.